# Is it possible to download cli from maven?

Tags: maven, npm

With npm, its common to do something like

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

I'm looking to do a similar thing with Maven, as the project I'm working on uses Maven as a build tool (It's a Java project).

Is it possible to do something similar with Maven like

```
mvn install awesome-cli
awesome-cli init CoolProject
```

#### Questions

- Is it possible to publish a CLI to Maven?
- Is it possible to download and install it with Maven?

Comment: So you have the idea to download a package which is installed on the system to be accessible for command line?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Maven does not work that way. You can download jars with Maven and start them using `java -jar...`. But this is probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Maven project is usually done via Archetypes. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html for more info on that.

If you already have an existing project, then you just need to have Maven installed and run one of it's commands. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html for some introductory information.